# How to perform marshalling and unmarshalling of XML file?

Tags: jaxb

I need to perform marshalling and unmarshhaling of this XML 
code :

```
<GlobalConfig>
    <DataSources>
        <DataSource id='1' source="query" type="static" queryId="111" dbInstance="test" urlId="1" urlFunction="/getData" dataProvider=""/>
        <DataSource id='2' source="query" type="static" queryId="112" dbInstance="ng" urlId="1" urlFunction="/getData" dataProvider=""/>
        <DataSource id='3' source="query" type="static" queryId="113" dbInstance="test" urlId="1" urlFunction="/getData" dataProvider=""/>
        <DataSource id='4' source="query" type="static" queryId="115" dbInstance="test" urlId="1" urlFunction="/getData" dataProvider=""/>
    </DataSources>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question exactly? What is the context? Please make sure you ask a good quality question. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GlobalConfig {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "DataSources")
    protected List<DataSource> dataSources;

    private static JAXBContext context;

    private GlobalConfig() {
        /* For JAXB */
    }

    /**
     * @return A marshaller for instances of {@link GlobalConfig}.
     * @throws JAXBException
     *             If the marshaller cannot be obtained.
     */
    public static Marshaller getMarshaller() throws JAXBException {
        final Marshaller marshaller = getJAXBContext().createMarshaller();

        try {
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        } catch (PropertyException __) {
            System.out.println("Cannot format XML of GlobalConfig.");
            /* That's okay */
        }

        return marshaller;
    }

    /**
     * @return An unmarshaller for instances of {@link GlobalConfig}
     * @throws JAXBException
     *             If the unmarshaller cannot be obtained.
     */
    public static Unmarshaller getUnmarshaller() throws JAXBException {
        final Unmarshaller um = getJAXBContext().createUnmarshaller();
        um.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
        return um;
    }

    /**
     * @return The {@link JAXBContext} to use to marshall/unmarshall instances of
     *         {@link GlobalConfig}
     * @throws JAXBException
     *             If the context cannot be obtained.
     */
    private synchronized static JAXBContext getJAXBContext() throws JAXBException {
        if (context == null)
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(GlobalConfig.class);
        return context;
    }

    public static class DataSource {

        @XmlAttribute
        protected int id;
        @XmlAttribute
        protected String source;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
        protected String type_;
        @XmlAttribute
        protected String dbInstance;
        @XmlAttribute
        protected String urlFunction;
        @XmlAttribute
        protected String dataProvider;

        private DataSource() {
            /* For JAXB */
        }

    }
```

Use the getMarshaller and getUnmarshaller methods to marshal/unmarshal.